# Best Comparison Algorithm using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, algorithm, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering what was the best approach to compare multiple objects that are created and having the state of the objects changed to Inactive (Deleted), while creating history and dependencies.

This also means im comparing past and present objects inside a relational table (MarketCookies).

```
Id     |    CookieID   |  MarketID
```

The ugly solution i found was calculating how many objects had i changed.
For this purpose lets call the items of the Past: ListP
And the new items: ListF
I divided this method into three steps:

1 - Count both lists;
 2 - Find the objects of ListP that are not present in List F and change their state to Inactive and update them;
 3 - Create the new Objects and save them.

But this code is very difficult to maintain.. How can i make an easy code to maintain and keep the functionality? 
Market Modal:

```
 public class Market()
 {
    public ICollection<Cookie> Cookies {get; set;}
 }
```

Cookie Modal:

```
 public class Cookie()
 {
   public int Id {get;set;}

   //Foreign Key
   public int CookieID {get;set}

   //Foreign Key
   public int MarketID {get;set;}
 }
```

Code:

```
  public void UpdateMarket (Market Market, int Id)
  {
     var ListP = MarketCookiesRepository.GetAll()
                 .Where(x => x.MarketID == Id && Market.State != "Inactive").ToList();
     var ListF = Market.Cookies.ToList();
     int ListPCount = ListP.Count();
     int ListFCount = ListF.Count();

     if(ListPCount > ListFCount)
     {
         ListP.Foreach(x => 
         {
            var ItemExists = ListF.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if(ItemExists == null)
            {
               //Delete the Object
            }
         });

         ListF.Foreach(x => 
         {
            var ItemExists = ListP.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if(ItemExists == null)
            {
               //Create Object
            }
         });
     }
     else if(ListPCount < ListFCount)
          {
              ListF.Foreach(x => 
              {
                 var ItemExists = ListP.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                 if(ItemExists == null)
                 {
                   //Create Objects
                 }
              });

              ListP.Foreach(x => 
              {
                 var ItemExists = ListF.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                 if(ItemExists == null)
                 {
                   //Delete Objects
                 }
              });
          }
          else if(ListPCount == ListFCount)
               {
                   ListP.Foreach(x => 
                   {
                        var ItemExists = ListF.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                        if(ItemExists == null)
                        {
                           //Delete Objects
                        }
                   });

                   ListF.Foreach(x => 
                   {
                       var ItemExists = ListP.Where(y => y.Id == x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                        if(ItemExists == null)
                        {
                           //Create Objects
                        }
                   });
               }
  }
```

Comment: Look at Sets specifically the contains and add methods. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you could simply do an except select Statement, which has the same functionality? or do I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, it's hard to know for sure what even a good implementation would look like, never mind "the best". But, based on your description, it seems like the LINQ `Except()` method would actually serve your needs reasonably well. For example:

```
public void UpdateMarket (Market Market, int Id)
{
    var ListP = MarketCookiesRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.MarketID == Id && Market.State != "Inactive").ToList();
    var ListF = Market.Cookies.ToList();

    foreach (var item in ListP.Except(ListF))
    {
        // set to inactive
    }

    foreach (var item in ListF.Except(ListP))
    {
        // create new object
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that your objects have overridden `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. If not, you can provide your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the above. For example:

```
// General-purpose equality comparer implementation for convenience.
// Rather than declaring a new class for each time you want an
// IEqualityComparer<T>, just pass this class appropriate delegates
// to define the actual implementation desired.
class GeneralEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals;
    private readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCode;

    public GeneralEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        _equals = equals;
        _getHashCode = getHashCode;
    }

    public bool Equals(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return _equals(t1, t2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T t)
    {
        return _getHashCode(t);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
public void UpdateMarket (Market Market, int Id)
{
    var ListP = MarketCookiesRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.MarketID == Id && Market.State != "Inactive").ToList();
    var ListF = Market.Cookies.ToList();
    IEqualityComparer<Cookie> comparer = new GeneralEqualityComparer<Cookie>(
        (t1, t2) => t1.Id == t2.Id, t => t.Id.GetHashCode());

    foreach (var item in ListP.Except(ListF, comparer))
    {
        // set to inactive
    }

    foreach (var item in ListF.Except(ListP, comparer))
    {
        // create new object
    }
}
```